# Ubuntu 14.04 install gcc-4.5 and g++4.5

Tags: gcc, g++, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install gcc-4.5 and g++-4.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5 g++-4.5 gcc-multilib g++-multilib` but the following errors appeared:

```
Package gcc-4.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package g++-4.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-4.5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-4.5' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Get it from an older ubuntu distribution. Why do you need exactly that version?

Comment: Could you please go into some more details? Because some modules such as llvm can be compiled with this version, but not gcc-4.6. [link](https://github.com/columbia/xtern)

Comment: Go to askubuntu.com for more details on how to do strange things with the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

gcc-4.5 or g++4.5 is not in most Ubuntu software distributions. If you are trying to get exactly this version, see [gcc releases](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) and [successful builds](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/buildstat.html).

Another option is to use [“PPA for Ubuntu Toolchain Uploads (restricted)” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)'s edition. In your case, add

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

to your source list, and run `sudo apt-get update`. You'll be able to use `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5`.

Comment: The PPA for Ubuntu Toolchain Uploads doesn't appear to have any older compilers for 14.04 (if you filter on 'trusty' the old ones disappear from the list).